# Can you guys recommend one model that has the best fit to this dataset with low r square estimation?

Tags: python, model, regression, curve-fitting, least-squares

I have already to fit it with polynomial with degree 2,3,4,5 and I can find the line that fit to the data but when I calculate the r square, the fitting line is useless. So can anyone recommend the model to use in this case. And here is the picture of my model.[Here is the picture of my dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AREBn.png).

Here is my x:

```
[16.82819759 17.02819759 17.22819759 17.42819759 17.62819759 17.82819759
 18.02819759 18.22819759 18.42819759 18.62819759 18.82819759 19.02819759
 19.22819759 19.42819759 19.62819759 19.82819759 20.02819759 20.22819759
 20.42819759 20.62819759]
```

Here is my y:

```
[ 3.93765301e+02  4.52594476e+02  4.75051340e+02  4.66863642e+02
  4.19903227e+02  3.56137042e+02  2.57671681e+02  1.44879082e+02
 -9.58553830e-01 -1.54569017e+02 -3.02841479e+02 -4.65624470e+02
 -6.29904237e+02 -7.70058305e+02 -8.91688224e+02 -9.94604656e+02
 -1.06898321e+03 -1.11293496e+03 -1.13248293e+03 -1.11271251e+03]
```

Answer (score 0):

The shape of the curve looks like an arc of sinusoid. So, we try the function below :

[image]

$\omega$ can be guessed by inspection and then linear regression gives approximate values of a, b, c.

If one cannot guess $\omega$ one have to use a software for non-linear regression. The result is $\omega$ = 0.99975 which is very close to the guessed value =1.

Comment: And If we want to calculate coefficient of that function from scratch, we need to least square estimation right?

Comment: In see no scratch in your question.

Comment: Your question is : "can anyone recommend the model to use in this case". The recommended model is the sinusoidal model. This answers to the question. Right ?